# best practice to include a frontend npm package with css/js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, gulp

I just started using NPM, Gulp etc.
Until now I only had NPM packages which either consisted of only JS or CSS/SASS.
What I did was, depending on the package:

- copy to the package to a vendor directory so I can work with it (in case of bourbon)
- just let gulp grab the file and concatenate it to my main.js or main.css

Now I have the fancybox NPM Package which consists of CSS and JS.
Should I also just grab the CSS separately from the JS and process it (copy, concatenate, rename etc.)?

After reading multiple blogs about handling NPM (Frontend) Packages I'm still not sure what's the best way to handle such a package.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guess it's okay to depend on the package installed in node_modules (or bower modules) itself.

You can include both css and js file in appropriate vendor.css and vendor.js files being built by your build system.

I would rather not copying it to some vendor folder, but include in vendor file directly.

Comment: thanks, why wouldn't you create a local copy in some vendor folders?
My idea was that I wouldn't be tightly coupled to node packages.

But otherwise, you say, seperating js and css from a single npm-package is a valid option?

Comment: I mean it's great to use npm or bower, and then do not copy into vendor folder. So your project will be easy to install via npm install or bower install and then you can just trigger build system (gulp, grunt) pointed to the package in node_modules or bower_components. If you want to update - no need to copy to vendor folder. You can just call npm update or bower update. Doing copies you're increasing amount of work you will need to do to maintain packages up-to date. Npm or bower can do that for you!

Comment: I did copy all the files via gulp. So they are automatically copied everytime I build my project (this is Visual Studio specific)